# Вывод даты из mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Вывожу дату из бд

```
print_r($service);
echo "<br>";
$now = $service['data'];
$time = date("F Y", $now);
echo $time;
```

На экране:

> Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 6 [appartament] => 5 [data] =>
>   2015-10-15 00:38:34 [price] => 500 ) )  January 1970

Что я неправильно делаю с датой, почему выводиться январь 1970, как вывести мою дату?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте

```
print_r($service);
echo "<br>";
$now = $service[1]['data']; // правильный индекс 1
$time = date("F Y", strToTime($now));
echo $time;
```

Comment: Спасибо,но теперь дата вообще не выводиться

Comment: $time = date("F Y", strToTime($now));
На экране все также январь 1970

Comment: благодарю и стыжусь)